# SQL left join get matching records as true or false columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables - items table and regions table as below.

| item_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

| item_id | region | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK | A |
| 1 | NA | B |
| 2 | UK | A |
| 2 | MX | C |
| 3 | SA | D |
| 3 | UK | A |
| 4 | MX | C |
| 4 | SA | D |
| 5 | IT | E |
| 6 | IN | F |
| 6 | CN | H |

I want the result to look like this :

| item_id | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 6 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

So far I have written the below SQL and the result looks like the below table. Please guide me in how to get the desired result as shown above.

```
Select
ho.item_id,
Case when ho.item_id = rgn.item_id and rgn.region_id ='A' then FALSE Else TRUE end as UK,
Case When ho.item_id = rgn.item_id and rgn.region_id ='B' then FALSE ELSE TRUE end as NA ,
Case When ho.item_id = rgn.item_id and rgn.region_id ='C' then FALSE ELSE TRUE end as MX,
Case When ho.item_id = rgn.item_id and rgn.region_id ='D' then FALSE ELSE TRUE end as SA,
Case When ho.item_id = rgn.item_id and rgn.region_id ='E' then FALSE ELSE TRUE end as IT

from
    item_table ho
    left join region_table as rgn on ho.item_id = rgn.item_id
where
    rgn.region_id in (
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E'
    ) order by ho.item_id desc
;
```

Result comes like this, where item ID is repeated multiple times, how to get only 1 entry for each item with corresponding TRUE or FALSE in columns.

| item_id | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 1 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 6 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is :

- putting "*TRUE*" value when the region matches the column, NULL otherwise
- aggregating the NULL values with the `MAX` function, so that the regions with no "*region_id*" corresponding to the field, will have the NULL anyways
- changing NULL values to "*FALSE*" using the `COALESCE` function

```
SELECT item_id,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN region_id = 'A' THEN 'TRUE' END), 'FALSE') AS A,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN region_id = 'B' THEN 'TRUE' END), 'FALSE') AS B,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN region_id = 'C' THEN 'TRUE' END), 'FALSE') AS C,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN region_id = 'D' THEN 'TRUE' END), 'FALSE') AS D,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN region_id = 'E' THEN 'TRUE' END), 'FALSE') AS E
FROM regions
GROUP BY item_id
```

If you don't want item_id = 6, then add a `LEFT JOIN` between the "*items*" table and this table.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vucoj8tZkW3AgSZAkK9r5Q/0).

Answer (score 0):

If you want only items, that have entries in region table, then no need to join table with items. Aggregate function `bool_or` will be helpful:

```sql
Select
  item_id,
  bool_or(region_id ='A') as UK,
  bool_or(region_id ='B') as NA,
  bool_or(region_id ='C') as MX,
  bool_or(region_id ='D') as  SA,
  bool_or(region_id ='E') as  IT
from region_table 
where
    region_id in (
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E'
    ) group by item_id order by item_id desc;
```